# q - internal state in while loop

Tags: kdb, q-lang

In q, I am trying to call a function `f` on an incrementing argument `id` while some condition is not met.

The function `f` creates a table of random length (between 1 and 5) with a column `identifier` which is dependent on the input `id`:

```
f:{[id] len:(1?1 2 3 4 5)0; ([] identifier:id+til len; c2:len?`a`b`c)}
```

Starting with `id=0`, `f` should be called while `(count f[id])>1`, i.e. so long until a table of length 1 is produced. The `id` should be incremented each step.

With the "repeat" adverb I can do the while condition and the starting value:

```
{(count x)>1} f/0
```

but how can I keep incrementing the `id`?

Comment: I think there's an issue with the way you have set up your function, you pass a number but return a table so for the second iteration you will be passing the table back in as `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this will fix your issue but I was able to get it to work by incrementing `id` inside the function and returning it with each iteration:

```
q)g:{[id] len:(1?1 2 3 4 5)0; id[0]:([] identifier:id[1]+til len; c2:len?`a`b`c);@[id;1;1+]}
```

In this case `id` is a 2 element list where the first element is the table you are returning (initially `()`) and the second item is the `id`. By amending the exit condition I was able to make it stop whenever the output table had a count of 1:

```
q)g/[{not 1=count x 0};(();0)]
+`identifier`c2!(,9;,`b)
10
```

If you just need the table you can run `first` on the output of the above expression:

```
q)first g/[{not 1=count x 0};(();0)]
identifier c2
-------------
3          a
```

The issue with the function `f` is that when using over and scan the output if each iteration becomes the input for the next. In your case your function is working on a numeric value put on the second pass it would get passed a table.